Confused about "no observations" error when using a foreach command
I am using a for each command to run regressions in a panel data set for each fips id, which is unique. However, I get an error message saying that there are no observations, even when observations exist (see screenshot below). How can I fix this?
[Screenshot of Error Message]
(https://i.sstatic.net/JgJea62C.png)
Here is my code:
`clear
import excel "sheet_1", sheet("Data") firstrow
save hpi_reg_data.dta
use hpi_reg_data.dta, clear

**Data Cleaning**
drop series
drop if date < mdy(1, 1, 1990)
sort fips date

gen year = year(date)
gen trend = year - 1989
drop if missing(fips) | missing(date) | missing(hpi) | missing(county_code) | missing(state_code) | missing(year) | missing(trend) 
destring hpi, replace
gen lnhpi = ln(hpi) 

**Regressions**
tempfile original_data
save `original_data', replace

levelsof fips, local(fips_list)
foreach id of local fips_list {
    display "Running regression for fips ID: `id'"
    use `original_data', clear 
    keep if fips == `id'
     if _N == 0 {
        display "No observations for fips ID: `id'"
        continue
    }
    di "Number of observations after filtering: " _N
    di "Current fips ID in subset: " fips[1]
    xtset fips trend
    xtreg lnhpi trend, fe
 log using regression_results_`id'.log, replace
    xtreg lnhpi trend, fe
    log close 
}`

I tried to drop any fips id's that were missing and validated that no data was missing.

Hi! One of the most important uses of tags on this site is so that people who are experts on a particular topic will find your question among the millions of others on the site. For instance, you should tag the programming language you're using, any major libraries or tools which are relevant to the question, etc, rather than just picking out keywords like "foreach".

Also, please do not upload images of code/data/errors, as discussed on this FAQ page.
